# Why Visual Studio Crashes while developing BizTalk projects?

Tags: visual-studio, biztalk

When developing BizTalk projects in latest version of Visual Studio 2019 it's crashing.

It's working fine in Visual Studio 16.4

But in later versions(16.4+) it's crashing. Why? And how to avoid?

Comment: You would probably have to raise this with Microsoft.  There is not enough information for us to help you

Comment: Which CU have you applied, and did you update Visual Studio install the latest version of BizTalk Server Visual Studio extension?